# Puppeteer unable to spoof canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, puppeteer, fingerprint, fingerprinting

I want to stop people from fingerprinting my puppeteer browsers, so Im writing a canvas spoofer. The ideea is to get the actual computted dataURL, and then change a little bit of it and set the changed data. This is the code:

```
      const originalFunction = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;

      const getCanvasProxyHandler = {
        apply: function (target, ctx, args) {
          const result = utils.cache.Reflect.apply(target, ctx, args)
          let canvas_element = ctx.cloneNode()
          let canvas_context = canvas_element.getContext("2d")
          console.log(0)

          let image = new Image()
          image.src = result;
          canvas_context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

          console.log(1)


          let new_result = originalFunction.apply(canvas_element, args)
          console.log(2)

          return new_result
        }
      }

      utils.replaceWithProxy(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toDataURL', getCanvasProxyHandler)
```

It prints 0 and 1 succesfully, but something happens at new_result. Nothing happens, no errors, but no result from toDataURL, and 2 doesn't print.

I belive it runs in a loop, since it calls toDataURL when Im calling toDataURL, which is why I grab the originalFunction, but even after trying to bind it using

```
 const originalFunction = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.bind({});
```

it still doesn't work

I would want originalFunction.apply(canvas_element, args) to actually work and return something, not timeout

Comment: Could I get a response please?